# Drop Off Funnel in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, analytics, window-functions

I have a table that has user_seq_id and no of days a user was active in the program. I want to understand the drop-off funnel. Like how many users were active on day 0 (100%) and on day 1, 2 and so on.

Input table :

```
create table test (
    user_seq_id int ,
    NoOfDaysUserWasActive int
);

insert into test (user_seq_id , NoOfDaysUserWasActive)
    values (13451, 2), (76453, 1), (22342, 3), (11654, 0),
           (54659, 2), (64420, 1), (48906, 5);
```

I want Day, ActiveUsers, and % Distribution of these users.

[image: table&output]

Comment: Is `NoOfDaysUserWasActive` just a total, or does it mean number of consecutive days ending today/yesterday? If it's just a total, do you have enough input data to inform the output you are looking for? Unless your number of days is trailing and up to date, it looks like you would also need more user/activity information in order to form user cohorts to make up your drop-off funnel.

Comment: NoOfDaysUserWasActive is the total no of days a user was active on the program. For eg: user- 13451 used it for 2 days and then deleted the account. Same way user-11654 deleted the account on the same day. So it is basically retention for each user. Hope that answered your question.

Comment: Oh, so you don't want cohorts. Or, more precisely, you want just one single cohort being your entire dataset. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method doesn't use window functions at all.  Just a list of days and aggregation:

```
select v.day, count(t.user_seq_id),
       count(t.user_seq_id) / c.cnt as ratio
from (select 0 as day union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5
     ) v(day) left join
     test t
     on v.day <= t.NoOfDaysUserWasActive cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt from test) c
group by v.day, c.cnt
order by v.day asc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b4a64b19a0d10a2e26043ae421522780) is a db<>fiddle.

The mention of window function suggests that you are thinking:

```
select NoOfDaysUserWasActive,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by NoOfDaysUserWasActive desc) as cnt,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by NoOfDaysUserWasActive desc) / sum(count(*)) over () as ratio
from test
group by NoOfDaysUserWasActive
order by NoOfDaysUserWasActive
```

The problem is that this does not "fill in" the days that are not explicitly in the original data.  If that is not an issue, then this should have better performance.

Comment: Thanks so much, this window function is exactly what I was looking for.